# How to combine hierarchical lists into one while respecting the hierarchy of each one of them using networkx and python?

Tags: python, sorting, networkx, hierarchical, topological-sort

For a medical application I want to combine several lists into one list. The items in each list represent actions to be taken for a specific disease.
For instance the list `Malaria` would look like that:

1. 'Give Malaria medication'
2. 'Give antibiotics'
3. 'Tell patient to come back tomorrow'
4. 'Give a warm lemon tea'

A second list for `Bacterial sore throat` would be this:

1. 'Give antibiotics'
2. 'Give paracetamol'
3. 'Give a warm lemon tea'
4. 'Warm the patient'

The actions in each list are hierarchical. That means that the more important tasks are mentioned first.

The lists themselves have a hierarchy as well, so `Malaria` is higher than `Bacterial sore throat`.

I need to combine those lists into a global one, that has the items sorted in a way that both hierarchies are preserved. This would be the case that a patient has both `Malaria` AND `Bacterial sore throat` and receives treatment according to the importance of each action.

For this case I would want this list:

1. 'Give Malaria medication' (from Malaria list because it is higher than sore throat)
2. 'Give antibiotics' (covers an action from both lists)
3. 'Tell patient to come back tomorrow' (from Malaria list)
4. 'Give Paracetamol' (more important than warm tea as seen in `sore throat`)
5. 'Give a warm lemon tea' (covers an action from both lists)
6. 'Warm the patient'

Currently this sorting is done by hand, but it becomes too complex with 50+ diseases.
I have looked into `networkx` trying to do a `topological sort` but I guess this is not the right approach.

It becomes more complex when sorting is not possible and the actions are in reverse order.
For instance in `Diarrhoea` there are

- make the patient drink
- give treatment

while in `Severe Diarrhoea` these are in reverse order

- give treatment
- make the patient drink

In this case I want the solution to double an item in the global list to

- give treatment
- make the patient drink
- give treatment

Is there a way to solve at least one of those steps?

Comment: If you merge your 3 lists, what is the final output (Malaria, Bacterial sore throat and Severe Diarrhoea)?

Comment: @Corralien thank you. No, it would be (Malaria, Severe Diarrhoea, Diarrhoea, Bacterial sore throat) but this is just an example out of 50+ diseases that are listed in a hierarchy.

Comment: My feeling is the topological_sort is the right idea but you have to break cycle first to keep a DAG.

Comment: Can you solve this case: `P1 = [A, B, C, D]` and `P2 = [B, A, E, F]`. What is the final output. P1 has an higher priority than P2 obviously. This is an extended case of Severe Diarrhoea and Diarrhoea

Comment: @Corralien, Thanks for asking. This would give `[A, B, A, C, D, E, F]`. 
A display condition is attached to each element. In the final list the first `A` is only displayed if `P1`, the `B`  is displayed if `P1` OR `P2`, the second `A` only if `P2`. Like that, if the patient only has `P1` it would show `[A,B,C,D]`, if only `P2` it would show `[B,A,E,F]`. And if both, it would show `[A,B,C,D,E,F]`

Comment: When you double an item what decide which one to double? Why can't your global list be `['make the patient drink', 'give treatment', 'make the patien drink']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Corralien that once you have a DAG, topological sort is still the way to go. You just have to break the ties between elements that are at the same hierarchy level correctly. This can be done with `nx.lexicographical_topological_sort`.

```
import networkx as nx

malaria = ['give malaria medication', 'give antibiotics', 'tell patient to come back tomorrow', 'give warm lemon tea']
bacterial_sore_throat = ['give antibiotics', 'give paracetamol', 'give warm lemon tea', 'warm patient']

edges = list(zip(malaria[:-1], malaria[1:])) + list(zip(bacterial_sore_throat[:-1], bacterial_sore_throat[1:]))
graph = nx.from_edgelist(edges, nx.DiGraph)

def sort_function(item):
    if item in malaria:
        return '01'
    elif item in bacterial_sore_throat:
        return '02'
    else:
        raise ValueError

print(list(nx.lexicographical_topological_sort(graph, sort_function)))

# ['give malaria medication', 'give antibiotics', 'tell patient to come back tomorrow', 'give paracetamol', 'give warm lemon tea', 'warm patient']
```

Comment: I am still not very clear on the hierarchy -  what happens if `bacterial_sore_throat = ['give paracetamol', 'give antibiotics', 'give warm lemon tea', 'warm patient']`? Is the second item in the combined list then antibiotics or paracetamol?

Comment: @Mortz `give paracetamol`, as per > step 4. 'Give Paracetamol' (more important than warm tea as seen in sore throat).

Comment: @Mortz in this case the element it would be: `['give Malaria medication', 'give paracetamol', 'give antibiotics', 'tell the patient to come back tomorrow', ...]`

Comment: There is no problem with the 2 first diseases. The problem is with the 2 last because there is a cycle. You have to break it. Using `lexicographical_topological_sort` doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Corralien Agreed. This is a partial answer, but then again OP was looking for a "way to solve at least one of those steps".

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can use the `+` operator to append one list to the end of the other -

For the case where 2 lists are to be combined, you can add (`+`) them and use the index of each item in the combined list as a sorting key to dedupe -

```py
malaria = ['give malaria medication', 'give antibiotics', 'tell patient to come back tomorrow', 'give warm lemon tea']
bacterial_sore_throat = ['give antibiotics', 'give warm lemon tea', 'warm patient']
combined_list = sorted(set(malaria + bacterial_sore_throat), key=lambda x: (malaria + bacterial_sore_throat).index(x))
print(*combined_list, sep='\n')
#give malaria medication
#give antibiotics
#tell patient to come back tomorrow
#give warm lemon tea
#warm patient
```

Note that in this case you are passing the diseases as `malaria + bacterial_sore_throat` when creating the combined list as `malaria` ranks higher than `bacterial_sore_throat`.

You can extend this logic to an arbitrary number of diseases using the `itertools.chain` function to combine diseases

```py
from itertools import chain
combined_list_2 = sorted(set(chain(malaria, bacterial_sore_throat)), key=lambda x: list(chain(malaria, bacterial_sore_throat)).index(x))
```

Comment: thank you, but I did not explain well the problem. I have now edited my question. The way you propose would not solve the issue, because the fusion of the lists does not incorporate the item hierarchy.

Comment: And what would happen to the combined order if for sore throat the order was - 1. Give paracetamol, 2. Give antibiotics, 3. Warm Tea, 4. Warm Patient ?